# Using Angular (2) routerLinkActive directive for inflected routes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've got this working, but I'm sure there's a better way to do this in Angular. Essentially I've the following:

Assume nested, inflected paths, e.g. `/logos` and `/logo/:id`

I have the following markup, which works:

```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" links="logo" routerLink="logos">
            Logos
            <span routerLink="logo" hidden></span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

This will properly cause the tab to activate on `/logo/:id`, however that span in there feels really hacky and incorrect.  If the paths are not inflected, e.g. `/logo` and `/logo/:id` or `/logos` and `/logos/:id` it works fine.  Do I just add another router link?  Should I add some other directive?  Do I need to go custom?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your router is setup like this; (assuming logos is after the root, i.e. `/logos`)

```ts
{
  path: 'logos',
  component: LogosComponent
},
{
  path: 'logo/:id',
  component: LogoComponent,
}
```

There's only two types of links you need to have:

Link to all the logos:
`<a routerLink='/logos'>All Logos</a>`

Link to a single logo:
`<a routerLink='/logo/specific-logo'>Specific Logo</a>` , where "specific-logo" is the ID of the logo you want to go to.

If you want to have `/logos` seem active while you are in the `/logo/specific-logo` directory, I don't think it's possible (except for the workaround you found). However, you can simulate it using a computed value, i.e.:

```html
<a class="nav-link" [class.active]="logoRouteActive" links="logo" routerLink="logos">
  Logos
</a>
```

```ts
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

// ...

constructor(private router: Router) { /** ... */ }

get logoRouteActive(): boolean {
  return this.router.isActive('/logo', false) || this.router.isActive('/logos', false);
}
```

Comment: The former is how I have my routes laid out, the issue is I want the router link to activate for both cases of `/logos` and `/logo/:id` while preserving the inflection.  I realize that using the child route approach, or even skipping inflecting the route names will accomplish that end, but the inflection is what I'm after.  I realize it's pedantic, but it helps maintain consistency, e.g. `/logos` is a list of logos, and `/logo/:id` is the details fora a single logo  `/logos/:id` can be figured out, but it doesn't match up with the many:one relationship.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll try to adjust my answer as so

Comment: Thanks.  That's how I've got things set up now, but the issue I'm encountering is still that when I'm looking at `/logo/<specific-id>`, the link in my nav, which is `routerLink='/logos'` doesn't have its `routerLinkActive` directive activated, which having that span in my example is able to trigger.  I've even tried different variations using the `matcher` property on my Route instead of `path`, but no luck.

Comment: Oh, so your question is how to have both the `/logos` routerLink seem active *while* `/logo/<specific-id>` is active? Insanity! I'd probably use a variable inside your class to simulate it. I'll update my answer again (I hope I'm understanding correctly now! haha)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. And that makes it more explicit than having to do weird hoops with the router or fake it using nested hidden links.

Comment: Glad I could help! Thanks for bearing with me, haha